Why do I get a Clustered Index Scan instead of a Table Scan?
I have these simple tables, one without indexes and the other with only a primary key and clustered index on id:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTableWithoutPk]([id] [int] NOT NULL, [category_id] int NULL)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTableWithPk]   ([id] [int] NOT NULL, [category_id] int NULL, 
  CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC))

If I do this query with a WHERE clause, I get, as expected, a Table Scan:
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[MyTableWithoutPk] where [category_id] = 100


If I do the same query to the MyTableWithPk, I still expect a Table Scan as there is no index on category_id. But I get a Clustered Index Scan!
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[MyTableWithPk] where [category_id] = 100


What am I missing?
I checked also Table Scan and Index Scan in SQL, and it also says:

If there is no index on category_id then a table scan will be performed


Table scan is if you have no clustered index, otherwise the data is the clustered index, so you get an index scan

If you configure a PRIMARY KEY, Database Engine automatically creates a clustered index, unless a clustered index already exists.
An index scan is performed on an indexed table if a table has a clustered index created on it.
Usually index scan is less expensive than a table scan. An Index scan significantly reduces the number of I/O read operations; it often outperforms a table scan.

One downvote reason (if you hover over it) is lack of research, hence its fairly common for duplicates to get downvoted if they are easy to find. (not me this time).
